# How to rotate UIImageView backwards into screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiimageview

I am trying to animate my UIImageView to tilt slightly to the left and tilting slightly back into the screen. I am using the following code to animate the slightly left tilt, but I don't know how to animate the UIImageView tilting back into the screen.

```
UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
     self.screenImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi/8)
})
```

Comment: You can't use a core graphics transform since it only operates in 2D space. You can use a core animation transform layer https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/135/how-to-render-uiviews-in-3d-using-catransformlayer

Comment: See discussion of "depth" in my book, http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html#_depth